# Convert string TYPE into array of chars TYPE

Tags: typescript, types, beta

In TypeScript 4.1 which dev version is already avalible through npm there are support for [Recursive Conditional Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#recursive-conditional-types) and [Template literal types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types) what creates some really interesting opportunities

Let's assume we have following type

```
// type is '0123456';
const actualString = '0123456';
```

### Task

Split a string by characters into new array, but type of array elements should be preserved

```
// Unfortunately, type is string[]
const chars1 = actualString.split('');

// Throws error: string[] is not assignable ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
const chars2: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'] = actualString.split('');
```

### My take on this one

```
type StringToChars<BASE extends string> = BASE extends `${infer _}`
  ? BASE extends `${infer FIRST_CHAR}${infer REST}` // BASE is inferable
    ? [FIRST_CHAR, ...StringToChars<REST>] // BASE has at least one character
    : [] // BASE is empty string
  : string[]; // BASE is simple string

// type is ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
type Chars = StringToChars<'0123456'>;
```

### Problem

This solution works fine for strings lesser than 14 chars.

```
// Throws: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. (ts2589)
type LargeCharsArray = StringToChars<'0123456789 01234'>
```

Obviously it runs into typescript types recursion limit, after checking on 14th char it leaves us with `[<first 14 characters>, ...any[]]`.

### Question

This recursive type call looks really bad, so I was wondering, is there more reliable way to transform string type into array of chars type?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQJYGdQHIAMBGATAZgCwCsAbKgNwBQAxgPYB2S4oAhleAK7MA2AyuAE4I6Ac1ABeNFjxFSlCiFABVOgDMa-DnWbhYXSABoIMeMlCNBIgNoBdavUagqAC2b8kmcSzadeAocIA6JGguBHAAClRUAEo5KDhQPgthABUaAGEXNwAeACEAQR4AUVBYAA8dOgATFHN-AD5PAuLSithqlAADABIAbyEVWH5QAH0AX06KUFAAflBmkvLKmtAe-tUh0AAxAEkAJR4UkfSACXy9sb6Bzb2iw4mp6dnQS12Do9PzwwCfpP80zKuJDZW6Heq2J6gABcLwh0LMfis1jkCniJhQlgwqEMqEw2LQ2HxqFwRPwRMIRNItjRoEBbk8fxEAKywIwOAIJFQ9RRYBSTn4NAA7kgYSljIgGOBmHRwAhtAh6IgUOUqLAkEgEAA3XSQUBVWCwaAsaqgaA0dUIABGeglKiEYVgAVA4XASGwhAAHABOaIUGkAGVcwlgdKQ+X4-GYuokjNSGRZ2TZ0hIAHZvaApAQuUA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are rather shallow recursion limits, and the pull request implementing template literal types, [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) mentions that this is a pain point when you try to pull apart strings one character at a time.  From [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336#issuecomment-686232585) by the implementer:

> Note that these types pretty quickly run afoul of the recursion depth limiter. That's an orthogonal issue I'm still thinking about.

So for now I don't think there's a solution that's going to work for strings of arbitrary length.

---

That said, you can play around with the limit by breaking off larger chunks at a time so that you don't have to recurse as much.  There's probably some optimal way of doing this, but I just used trial and error to find something that increases the longest splittable string from ~14 to ~80 characters:

```
type StringToChars<T extends string> =
  string extends T ? string[] :
  T extends `${infer C0}${infer C1}${infer C2}${infer C3}${infer C4}${infer C5}${infer R}` ? [C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, ...StringToChars<R>] :
  T extends `${infer C0}${infer C1}${infer C2}${infer C3}${infer R}` ? [C0, C1, C2, C3, ...StringToChars<R>] :
  T extends `${infer C0}${infer R}` ? [C0, ...StringToChars<R>] : []


type WorksWith80 = StringToChars<'12345678911234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789612345678971234567898'>;
type Len80 = WorksWith80['length']; // 80

type BreaksWith81 = StringToChars<'123456789112345678921234567893123456789412345678951234567896123456789712345678981'>;
type Len81 = BreaksWith81['length']; // number
```

You can see that instead of just grabbing one character, we try to grab six.  If that fails, we go for four, and then fall back to one.

---

You might be able to push the limits farther by playing around with that, but I don't really see the point: this algorithm is *ugly* and is seemingly unmotivated without a bunch of comments on recursion limits; TS isn't quite ready for this stuff at the moment.  Hopefully @ahejlsberg will make this better sometime and I can come back here with better news.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201112#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwCoHsDCALAhvAM4A86UEAHsBMgCZFREIqoB8UAvFAFBRMs0FarQZRyAfgFI0AbQC6UAFx9xwmvUYADACQBvFADMI8KNgAMAX31GTZgIzWDyY6ewAmJ7bcBmLy7tsABZ-VzMAVlC7ACVLLSgpWQsAGgdUj3SfdKD08NSAOkK4GQwcAmISaLZFFX5yKg0xXWcwiyi3RxsAt08u1r8+mLiEqCTzdPt090yCosFSvEJSKprVepFNKGbvMytB01j4xJSoQvzi1ixFipXlUfkeR9BIKAB1THgAayJXxGBcAAc5i4sHmV3KpAA5PZ3D4guEAGwAdgBAE57DC4YiUaj3Jj4ci0T58di0UESYTUeEKTiETS0Uj6aiAZC2ABuHjPaAAGVoQJB7y+Pz+gPMskhABtaKh-pD5GyoAB6RVQIFPcDQABC8Ag+G+v3+APsIIuaHBSxI0NhBJxGOtpNxTOJ9sp5JdOOp7rRdK9qMZvqNrI5XKgvOQRpB2t1+pFRvFUrQsvlSpVyAArgBbABGJh4QA)